# Access overflow div inside TD

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to develop a drag-n-drop schedule tool, something like Fullcalendar.

I have opted for a table format and a rectangle div inside TD which represents task.

```
<table onDragEnd={dragend}>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}> <div id="drag" style={styleRect} draggable={true} onDragStart={drag}></div> </td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
      <td onDrop={drop} onDragOver={allowDrop}></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[image: Snippet]

I can drag and drop my rectangle task by clicking on the TD where the div is nested, but as you can see my rectangle task is overflowing on right TDs and I would be able to drag and drop the rectangle task by clicking on neighbor's TDs too.

To be more specific, I can drag and drop by clinking on TD 5 but my rectangle task is on the TD 6 and TD 7 too and I would be able to drag and drop here too.

I tried to put TD on `position:relative` `z-index:1` and div rectangle task on `z-index:2` `position:absolute`

Comment: So, your *task* shall only be in exactly one `td`?

Comment: No it can be on multiple TD visually but technically it is in a TD and its length is overflowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a special `class` while the element is being dragged. **Also be sure to append the `div` back to the `td` on `drop`.**

```js
function allowDrop(event){
  event.preventDefault()
};

function drag(event){
  event.target.classList.add("dragging");
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id)
};

function dragend(event){};

function drop(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var tSource = document.getElementById(data);
  
  if(tSource && event.target.tagName === 'TD'){
    event.target.appendChild(tSource);
    tSource.classList.remove("dragging");
  }
};
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

th{
  background: #3d3d3d;
  color: orange;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 25px
}

table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%
}

.draggable{
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

.dragging{
  background: red !important;
}

#drag2{
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 175px;
  z-index: 2 /*REM: If you want to be able to click in the overflow. If not, remove this property*/
}
```

```html
<table onDragEnd="dragend(event)">
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)">
        <div id="drag2" draggable="true" onDragStart="drag(event)" class="draggable"></div>
      </td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)">
        <div id="drag" draggable="true" onDragStart="drag(event)" class="draggable"></div>
      </td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td onDrop="drop(event)" onDragOver="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Yes but I still wouldn't be able to access the div from an other TD ?

Comment: @Kazuma Gaijin: I am not entirely certain what you mean. In case you want the *task* to overlap to other cells, you have to change it to `position: absolute`. I added it to my example as `#drag2`.

Comment: You see in the image, the task starts at 5 and ends at 7. To do this I put a div in TD 5 and make it overlaps. But if I want to drag it by clicking in the part which is between 6 and 7 it will not work. Becausemy task is in TD5 and I want to access it by clicking in TD7.

Comment: Well, I do not have your css. For me it works (the green one), as you can see in my example, by setting `postition: absolute; z-index: 2`. Without thoses, you can only click in the `td` the `div` is contained.